# How do I set and reset my hidden text field to empty using jquery code below?

Tags: jquery

I am using the code below to pop a text field onchange of certain drop-downs.  Works perfectly, but I ran into one issue and I can't seem to get it to work.  Onload, the hidden text box has "**Select**" as text within it.  {Select is the default 0 value}. If the user does not select anything from the dropdowns, then the text "**Select**" causes an error when the data is sent because it does not match a value that is on the receiving end.

I want to alter the code below to include the following:
onload >> hidden text field is set to empty/equals nothing
if value "Select" is in the hidden text feild, change to empty/equals nothing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("select#4359, select#4360, select#4361, select#4362, select#4374, select#4378").change(function(){
            $("#5334").val($(this).find(":selected").text());
        })
        .trigger('change');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand your requirement correctly. But i belive you are looking for something like, when the user select option other than select, set the text of that item to hidden, else set it to nothing. This code will do that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#5334").val("");
        $("select#4359, select#4360, select#4361, select#4362, select#4374, select#4378").change(function(){
            $("#5334").val("");
            var txt=$(this).find(":selected").text();
            if(txt!="Select")
            {
                $("#5334").val(txt);
            }     
        })
        .trigger('change');
 });
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/UXu7C/9/

Comment: Well for someone who didn't understand - you hit the nail right on the head.  Works perfectly!!! Thank you!!!!